# DLLImport with char * arguments. Only one character being passed

Tags: c#, c++, string, char, dllimport

I have written a C++ DLL with the following function exported

```
extern "C" BOOL WINAPI SetUserPassword(const char* u, const char* p)
```

When calling this from C# I am using the following code

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
private static extern int SetUserPassword(String user, String password);
```

Now when `SetUserPassword` is called I only get the first letter of each parameter.  I did some googling and found that `String` was perhaps not the best to use so tried using IntPtr and `Marshal.StringToBSTR()` but this didn't work either.

How should this be structured correctly? I am able to modify the C++ DLL if required.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only thing that makes sense is that your C# code is actually:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CharSet = Unicode)]
private static extern int SetUserPassword(String user, String password);
```

When you do this you pass a wide character based string to your C++ code and since it expects single byte characters it interprets the 0 byte in the second half of the first two byte character as a string terminator.

You should write:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CharSet = Ansi)]
private static extern int SetUserPassword(String user, String password);
```

Or in fact you could write it exactly as in your question because `Ansi` is the default.

---

And in fact it turns out that you are on CE which does not support `Ansi` character set and so the only reasonable solution is to make your C++ code accept wide character strings.

Comment: Ahhh! I forgot to mention im on WinCE.  All I did was change my C++ function to accept `wchar_t` and then converted that into an ANSI `std::string` and now it's all working - Thanks!

Comment: Agreed.  Or [MarshalAs].  A snippet that has "mydll.dll" was not copy/pasted.  Tsk, tsk, +1 for psychic debugging.