# C# calling C DLL, pass char * as parameter not correct

Tags: c#, dll, pinvoke, native

I am calling a DLL(C write)  in C# language in VS2012. mylib.dll is the native dll I am going to call in C# , and  mylib.dll will also call another mylib_another.dll also.

C function declaration as:

```
extern DECLSPEC_DLL BOOLEAN_TYPE SetConnection(char *dev, char *addr);
```

In My C#　 file , I declare it as:

```
[DllImport("C:\\mylib.dll", EntryPoint = "SetConnection", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static unsafe extern int SetConnection(StringBuilder  dev,  StringBuilder addr);
```

When I calling it in code ,I found that the string only passed one character, when I pass dev as"USB" , the native DLL only get a  "U" actually.

If I change  declaration to :

```
[DllImport("C:\\mylib.dll", EntryPoint = "SetConnection", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static unsafe extern int SetConnection(StringBuilder  dev,  StringBuilder addr);
```

Then it will raise an System.AccessViolationException Exception :

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
HResult=-2146232828
Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at QC.QTMDotNetKernel.DotNetKernel.RunDotNetTest(Object stateObject)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
InnerException: System.AccessViolationException
   HResult=-2147467261
   Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Any ideas about that ?

Have solved as below(the answer is for the first question, for the second one , that is because the mylib.dll called another native dll and the system did not find it).

A similar issue [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283820/dllimport-with-char-arguments-only-one-character-being-passed)

Comment: Those two declarations for `SetConnection()` are identical. Are they supposed to differ?

Comment: CharSet.Auto is wrong, make it Ansi.  StringBuilder is very likely to be wrong for a function whose starts with "Set", make it string.

Comment: Second one is: `CharSet = CharSet.Ansi`

when change to this , it raise System.AccessViolationException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you only receive one character like that, it normally means that you are passing a Unicode (UTF16) string to a C/C++ function that is expecting an 8 bit format such as ASCII, UTF8 or ANSI.

The 16-bit Unicode format ends up with one byte of its two bytes being set to zero for characters in the ASCII/ANSI range, and because a C/C++ program treats a zero byte as an end-of-string character, it truncates the string.

It's easy to try using ANSI to see if it helps; change

```
CharSet = CharSet.Auto
```

to

```
CharSet = CharSet.Ansi
```

Comment: Second one is: `CharSet = CharSet.Ansi`

when change to this , it raise System.AccessViolationException.

Comment: Yeah, this one is correct , the second problem about  `System.AccessViolationException` is because  in the native  dll,

Comment: Yeah, this one is correct , the second problem about  `System.AccessViolationException` is because  in the native  dll, I called another native dll called mylib_another.dll  and it  because I loaded the mylib.dll specificly from a full path, the mylib_another.dll in this path can not be loaded by main programm automatically.

So all these dll (except that one in load in your code) should be place with your main programme 's home directory to make sure it can loaded automatically .

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your p/invoke:

1. The calling convention looks to be `cdecl`. It's not specified in the native code and the most likely default is `cdecl`.
2. You are passing `StringBuilder` which is used for `out` parameters. Note that I am assuming that the two parameters are both input parameters.
3. The character set is wrong. The native code receives 8 bit encoded text.
4. You do not need to be using `unsafe`.

A corrected declaration is:

```
[DllImport(@"C:\mylib.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int SetConnection(string dev, string addr);
```

You can omit the specification of character set since ANSI is the default. Of course, it doesn't hurt to specify `CharSet=CharSet.Ansi` if you prefer to be explicit. There's no need to specify `EntryPoint` if it is the same name as the function that you declare.

Comment: I do need this line:
`CharSet=CharSet.Ansi` to solve the first problem.

Comment: No you do not. It is the default and it can be omitted. Clearly you cannot set it to `CharSet.Auto` as you did in the question, but the code in my answer is accurate.